# Pandas ".loc" method not working as expected

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Why is this working?

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = {'mynumbers': [51, 52, 53, 54, 55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers, columns =['mynumbers'])
df.loc[df['mynumbers'] <= 53, 'mynumbers'] = 'True'
print (df)
```

Output:

```
  mynumbers
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4     False
```

But this returns an error:

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = {'mynumbers': [51, 52, 53, 54, 55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers, columns =['mynumbers'])
print(df.loc[df['mynumbers']])
```

If in the first case I can use the "df.loc[df['mynumbers']]" statement as a conditional to compare values, why do I get an error when I simply try to print out the statement alone?

I understand that the index values that I pass into the .loc method yield a key error because there is no such key exist, but I do not understand that why does it works in the first instance?

Comment: The first condition is an assignment statement, after the boolean indexing, the True positions are replaced with string `True`, and the rest False. If you check the dtypes, you will notice that it is an object type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `df['mynumbers'] <= 53` you use a boolean indexer, that is a series that has the same index as `df` and either `True` or `False` as values:

```
>>> df['mynumbers'] <= 53
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: mynumbers, dtype: bool
```

This can be passed to `df.loc[]` or `df[]`:

```
>>> df[df['mynumbers'] <= 53]
   mynumbers
0         51
1         52
2         53
>>> df.loc[df['mynumbers'] <= 53, :]
   mynumbers
0         51
1         52
2         53
```

The other way to use `df.loc[]` is to pass in index values:

```
>>> df.loc[df.index]
   mynumbers
0         51
1         52
2         53
3         54
4         55
>>> df.loc[df.index[3:]]
   mynumbers
3         54
4         55
>>> df.loc[[1, 2]]
   mynumbers
1         52
2         53
```

However when you do `df.loc[df['mynumbers']]` you’re doing none of those 2 options. It’s trying to find the object `df['mynumbers']` in the index, as shown by the following error, and that doesn’t work:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([51, 52, 53, 54, 55], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. "df.loc[df['mynumbers'] <= 53" is not the same as "df.loc[df['mynumbers']]" on its own, but a boolean indexer.